# How I can prove that there is a bijection between the set $A$ and $ℤ$?

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory

Let $f:ℝ→ℝ$ be a real analytic function and not identically zero. Assume that $f$ has infinitely many **negative** zeros. Let us consider the set $A$ of points $(c_{k},0)$ where $c_{k}<0$ is a zero of the function $f$. Then my **question** is: How I can prove that there is a bijection between the set $A$ and $ℤ$?

Comment: @Alfonso Fernandez: Is there an explicit formula for that isomorphism?

Comment: The set of zeros of an analytic function doesn't necessarily admit a nice group/ring structure, so I'm not sure which kind of isomorphism you're looking for.

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez: A bijection is sufficient.

Comment: In what sense did you mean isomorphism?

Comment: Why the condition $c_k<0$? Can you even prove the set $A$ is nonempty?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Because other proofs show that this function have infinitely many negative zeros.

Comment: Assuming "other proofs" means additional information you have got but we haven't, you should have mentioned that hypothesis, as without it one cannot help you out. (It cannot refer to answers given here, as they do not and cannot prove infinitely many negative zeros to exist.) I have now added this to the question. Without the mention of "negative", the proper answer would be "you cannot prove it because it is not true; here is a counterexample".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be proven relying on two theorems:

1. Every uncountable set in $\mathbb{R}$ has a limit point.
2. Every two analytic functions that coincide on a set with a limit point are equal. (This is a well known and in my opinion very beautiful fact in complex analysis)

Therefore, if $A$ is uncountable, $A$ has a limit point and $f\equiv 0$, and otherwise $A$ is countable.

Proof of (1):

Assume $A$ has no limit point. Following the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, $A\cap[-n,n]$ must be finite for all $n$. Howerver, $$A = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(A\cap[-n,n])$$
and therefore $|A|\le\aleph_0$.

Comment: You only showed that $A$ is not uncountable. The question mentions $c_k<0$, which condition is not mentioned here at all.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $A$ is countable, it suffices to show that every point $a \in A$ is isolated.  That is, for every $a \in A$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that

$$(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) \cap A = \{a\}$$

Let $a \in A$, and consider the Taylor series for $f$ about $a$

$$f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty c_n(x - a)^n$$

which converges in some open interval $(a - R, a + R)$.  Let $c_k$ be the first coefficient not equal to $0$, so that

$$f(x) = \sum_{n = k}^\infty c_n(x - a)^n = (x - a)^k\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n + k}(x - a)^n$$

The function $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n + k}(x - a)^n$ is analytic in $(a - R, a + R)$ and so, $g$ is continuous at $a$, with $g(a) = c_k \ne 0$.  Let $\epsilon = \dfrac{|c_k|}{2}$.  By continuity, we can find $\delta > 0$, so that $|x - a| < \delta$ implies $|g(x) - c_k| < \epsilon$.  It follows that for every $x \in (a - \delta, a+ \delta) \setminus \{a\}$, $f(x) \ne 0$, and so $(a - \delta, a + \delta) \cap A = \{a\}$.

We conclude that every point of $A$ is isolated, and therefore, $A$ is countable.

Comment: Same comment as to the other answer and to the question. Why must $A$ be infinite?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: because $f$ has infinitely many zeros.

Comment: @AR1: But $A$ contains only **negative** zeros, and (before I changed the question) there was no way of knowing there were infinitely many of them (or indeed any at all).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: That assumption is independent of the current question. I assume from the beginning that f has infinitely many zeros.

Comment: @AR1. There are analytic functions that have infinitely many zeros, but for which the set $A$ is nonetheless finite, because most or all of the zeros are at positive values. Example, $x\mapsto \Gamma(-x)^{-1}$, (extended by continuity, so $0$ at all positive integers). For such a function all conditions of the original question are satisfied, but the conclusion is false. This shows that the assumption I added of having infinitely many ***negative*** zeros is **not independent** of the question.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Ok and thank you very much for clarification.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I believe I showed that $A$ is countable, which I'm allowing to mean finite or countably infinite.

Comment: @Brian: The question is about a bijection with $\Bbb Z$. Indeed it does not mention countable/uncountable. But by now it has been modified so that is is clear that by hypothesis $A$ is infinite.